# No Sound coming from Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, media-player

I ran my application and I can't get the sound working on the Android Emulator.
I checked and enabled the audio playback boolean in the `Eclipse` AVD Manager.
I also went into the sound options in the Android Emulator and put them up (no sound while putting them up).
I checked the box that says all selections will make a noise(still no sound).

My application uses the `MediaPlayer` class and I am running win7 x64 if that has anything to do with it.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: A possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63433663/5765771

Comment: For me this worked https://stackoverflow.com/a/68392331/3636099 change hw.audioInput=yes
hw.audioOutput=yes

Comment: Really dumb but for some reason focusing on the Android Virtual Devices window worked for me (and nearly gave me a heart attack)

Answer (score 38):

For OS X the Android Emulator uses the settings for "Sound Effects" so this is what I had to do to fix my issue:

1. Click the Apple icon in the top left, then click on System Preferences
2. Click on Sound
3. Click on "Sound Effects"
4. Set "Play sound effects through" to "Selected sound output device"
5. Set the Alert volume almost at max.

Somehow this had changed to use my monitors instead.

Comment: Do this settings *before* you start your avd.

Comment: Where is System Preferences? Is that in the emulator or somewhere Android Studio?

Comment: It is located under the Apple menu in the top left. I updated my answer to clarify.

Comment: All my sound settings were already at max (even the ones described in this answer) for months, even restarting my mac and the emulator (even using new ones) and restarting android studio, the media sound in the emulator is still mute or almost inaudible...

Comment: Did not work in macOs monterey. Tried this with the emulator off, cold booted it. No sound. Anyone have any steps from the past year or so that work?

Comment: @MatthewGoodwin have you  found the solution?

Comment: Did not help for me. Still no sound coming from android emulator.

Comment: working like a charm. Thanks, @TorreLasley upvoting the answer
Need to do these settings before Emulator get started

Comment: Do we have to set the setting back every time we're done working on the app?

Answer (score 16):

In Ubuntu 16.04, start the emulator and go to the Ubuntu → System Settings → Sound → Applications. Uncheck the mute checkbox and set the cursor at the middle position.

Comment: I am on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed and I didn't have qemu-system-x86_64 at all. The cause appeared to be in Android Studio - the one installed from Snap was having this problem. When I downloaded it and ran the downloaded version - only then I had qemu... in pulseaudio GUI and had sound from emulator.

Answer (score 8):

The solution on Ubuntu 16.04 consists in going to the System Settings → Sound → Application tab.

Then, unmute the Qemu-system … and increase the volume

[image]

Comment: Where is this screen in Ubuntu 20? I don't see Qemu system anywhere in the System/Settings/Sound screen.

Comment: I am on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed and I didn't have qemu-system-x86_64 at all. The cause appeared to be in Android Studio - the one installed from Snap was having this problem. When I downloaded it and ran the downloaded version - only then I had qemu... in pulseaudio GUI and had sound from emulator.

Comment: For those who are lost, try to run emulator from cmd, like -> ./emulator -avd my_emulator_name. This Qemu System will show in sound settings.

Comment: In my case, everything in Application was unmuted already. I solved it by selecting the correct output in the tab "Output" instead.

Answer (score 2):

On Debian 8 , you should open qemu-system after android emulator launching
[image]

Comment: I am on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed and I didn't have qemu-system-x86_64 at all. The cause appeared to be in Android Studio - the one installed from Snap was having this problem. When I downloaded it and ran the downloaded version - only then I had qemu... in pulseaudio GUI and had sound from emulator.

Answer (score 1):

my apps working fine with sound suddenly it stop sound because of some code changed. all other app sound also  stopped then i did below step now it is fine

try below

go to android emulator 
1.close the program
2.setting -> sound -->volumes ->increase sound value in  music video games and other media 
it will work

Answer (score 1):

On On Kubuntu , you should increase the playback stream of qemu-system after android emulator launching 
[image]

Comment: What happens if qemu-system.* doesn't show up in your Sound-->Applications settings?

Comment: I don´t know what operative system are you currently using. I thing qemu-system should send the sound to some audio driver.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: @IRGeekSauce did you find a solution?

Comment: Sadly I did not. Just testing on a real device for sounds for now.

Comment: Try to run emulator from command line, like: -> ./emulator -avd emulator_name. It worked in Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem : in a terminal, 
type pavucontrol (when emulator is running)
and another application using sound, that works, is running too (on pause).

Check if quemu-system and the other application use the same soundcard... In my case, this was the problem :quemu system was using a non working internal soundcard.

Answer (score -8):

Try pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>. I had a hard time to figuring this out.

Comment: You should at least explain what this is intended to do.

Comment: This is the only one that worked though