# genymotion does not make any sound

Tags: android, macos, audio, genymotion

there.
I'm using Genymotion for test.
I'm developing an android application.
This application can make a sound.
then 
I tried to test my android application.
But,it would not make a sound.

My environment is Macbook.
and
Virtual box is 5.1.
and
VMDevice is Google Nexus 4 with API level 22.
this would not make any sound even if i could change the volume of sound on genymotion.

[image]

And my virtual device setting is here.

Answer (score 9):

In genymotion FAQ page, 
https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/

> ### What are the VirtualBox versions compatible with Genymotion?
>
> - 5.1+ versions are not recommended as they lead to sound issues
> - To run virtual devices, you must install Oracle VM VirtualBox 5.0.28.
> - Genymotion might run with older versions but we cannot guarantee it.

so you should use version 5.0 or older to get sound working

Comment: Please update the answer to include 5.0.26 for Mac OSX. I spent a lot of time trying to get 5.0.28 to work on Max OSX.

Comment: 2018 : confirm ,  5.0.26  does work . latest ver didnt work. link : https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog-5.0#v26

Comment: The version _currently_ listed in the official FAQ is **6.0.4**: https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#compatible-virtualbox-versions

Answer (score 8):

It takes me a long time, finally got the answer.

Several versions of VirtualBox are known to cause issues in Genymotion.
For Genymotion to run properly, make sure you have the right version of VirtualBox installed:

Mac OS X: 5.0.26 (a sound issue prevents version 5.0.28 to run properly)
Windows: 5.0.28
Linux: 5.0.28
In any case, do not use versions 5.1.x, as they are known to cause sound issues and in some cases prevent Genymotion to start.

Answer (score 3):

For me, setting the sound effects destination in the Sound setting did the trick. You have to open the emulator after setting the destination.

Huge thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/40007818 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I also had no sound when using Windows 10 1709, VirtualBox 5.1.26 and Genymotion 2.11.0.

I noticed this line in VBox.log:

> Audio: Skipping to create input stream "[LUN#0] ac97.mc", as the host
>   audio backend reached its maximum of concurrent audio input streams

What solved my no audio issue was to **activate the "Stereomix"** in the recording devices in Windows Sound settings. For an unknown reason this was deactivated.

[image]