# Android emulator no sound in ubuntu

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, ubuntu, android-emulator

I am running android emulator in ubuntu-19.10 and I have attempted following solutions with no results,

[Link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265202/no-sound-coming-from-android-emulator)

[Link-2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200339/the-android-studio-emulator-doesnt-sound-ubuntu-19-10-distribution)

[Link-3](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/5tidzc/a_solution_for_pulseaudio_pa_context_connect/)

Error,

```
1:10 PM Emulator: pulseaudio: pa_context_connect() failed
1:10 PM Emulator: pulseaudio: Reason: Connection refused
1:10 PM Emulator: pulseaudio: Failed to initialize PA contextaudio: Could not init `pa' audio driver
```

Some notes on solution I tried,

When trying [Link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265202/no-sound-coming-from-android-emulator) i don't see "Qemu-system" in settings. Also created many different versions of AVDs but does seem to work.

After trying [Link-2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200339/the-android-studio-emulator-doesnt-sound-ubuntu-19-10-distribution) `pulseaudio -D` command errors out.

I have also tried [Link-3](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/5tidzc/a_solution_for_pulseaudio_pa_context_connect/) which looks like widely suggested solution in multiple blog posts. But still I find the same error on emulator startup. I would like to note that I am not smart enough understand this solution.

Thanks in advance for helping out.

Comment: please can you share your solution , i have the same problem....

Comment: @StanlyMedjo I didn't find any. I added bounty but no answers. I started testing with real device for audio related stuff.

Comment: @StanlyMedjo if you find somewhere then add here.

Comment: please how do you lunch your android studio, without the audio, cause even that  i have problems doing so, cause, when it lunches on my side, it console that error and close

Comment: @StanlyMedjo I am using vscode

Answer (score 6):

Same problem in Ubuntu 20.04, with Android Studio installed from Ubuntu Software. Tried everything (paprefs, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200339/no-sound-in-the-android-studio-emulator-on-msi-p65-with-ubuntu-19-10)), nothing worked. Uninstall Android Studio Snap and reinstall from tar package downloaded from Android Studio website, works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue on Ubuntu 20.04 but I fixed it by uninstalling the store version of Android Studio and following the installation instructions on the Official Android Studio website here: https://developer.android.com/studio/install

1. If you are running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, you need to install some 32-bit libraries with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
    lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386
```

2. To install Android Studio on Linux, proceed as follows:

Unpack the .zip file you downloaded to an appropriate location for your applications, such as within /usr/local/ for your user profile, or /opt/ for shared users.
If you're using a 64-bit version of Linux, make sure you first install the required libraries for 64-bit machines.

To launch Android Studio, open a terminal, navigate to the android-studio/bin/ directory, and execute studio.sh.
Select whether you want to import previous Android Studio settings or not, then click OK.
The Android Studio Setup Wizard guides you through the rest of the setup, which includes downloading Android SDK components that are required for development.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, runing Intellij on Ubuntu 20.04. I solved it by adapting a solution from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200339/no-sound-in-the-android-studio-emulator-on-msi-p65-with-ubuntu-19-10/1207025#1207025?newreg=b1cab1d0579e4de1956cd59f9ba22dad) link

I run this:

```
sudo ln -s /run/user/1000/pulse/native /run/user/1000/snap.intellij-idea-community/pulse
```

If you're using Android studio, just try to find "snap.intellij-idea-community" will be named differently, referring to your android studio installation.

Comment: This currently doesn't work in Ubuntu 21.04. The issue was supposedly fixed in https://github.com/snapcrafters/android-studio/pull/74 , but the changed setting doesn't work in Ubuntu 21.04 because `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is `/run/user/<uid>`. This horrible workaround worked for me, instead: `sudo ln -s /run/user/$UID/pulse /run/user/pulse`. It should be an easy fix in the snap store, but I don't know how compatible it will be.

Comment: @Guss I am running Ubuntu 21.10 and Android Studio (Snap) - tried your fix, which worked! (But only after restarting the Virtual Device)

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu, is possible open the emulator with terminal and change the sound in System Preferences. Works with the instant version of Android Studio. It works with the snap version of Android Studio.

First is needed to add the `emulator` command to the `PATH`.

This can be done by editing `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`. Preferably these lines should be placed at the end of the file.

```sh
export ANDROID_SDK_PATH=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export ANDROID_NDK_PATH=$HOME/Android/Sdk/ndk
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/Android/Sdk/platform-tools"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/Android/Sdk/emulator"
```

The PATH variable needs to be reloaded. This can be done manually, as shown below, or simply by opening another terminal:

```sh
source ~/.bashrc
# OR
source ~/.zshrc
```

Another way is to add `adb` and `android-sdk-platform-tools-common` packages to have the `emulator` command available. Package names may vary depending on the Ubuntu version.

After that, the `emulator` command can be used to list available emulators:

```sh
emulator -list-avds
```

Example of output:

```
Pixel_4_API_30
Pixel_C_API_30
```

Then can be opened one of the available emulators:

```sh
emulator @Pixel_4_API_30
```

Finally, the emulator probably will appear at the System Preferences:

[image: Sound Settings on Ubuntu]

Comment: Maybe you could specify where to put the path variable, like at the bottom of the files or sth. For a noob like me, editing blindly in `.bashrc` is really unpleasant. Anyway, after adding it, I can't do `emulator -list-avd`, I have to do `flutter emulator -list`, then `emulator @device_name`. So this worked for me.

Comment: Hello. I edited the post to put your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a `Snap` it's got strict requirements as far as `i/o`; that said, if the requirements are similar to those of running `Androidx86` using Vbox on Debian (I realize Qemu is a different environment, however, this *may* be of use for both Jbaba as well as future reference. Step one: make sure that you belong to the group `Qemu` (or the equivalent for Ubuntu/Snap?). Step two: make sure you belong to the group `pulseaudio`. Step three: make sure that Qemu is explicitly permitted to access whatever your audio output device is and that it's the device that pulseaudio is configured to output to. There should be a fairly intuitive way of seeing this using Qemu (it's been awhile, so I am not able to tell you where to find it). As for pulseaudio; its GUI will show you.

Answer (score 0):

I got crazy while trying to solve this issue but finally, it was solved. I figured out that we have to enable multiple simultaneous audio outputs in order to hear both sounds the emulator and the OS.

The solution is by installing ***paprefs*** small app as the following.

1- Install it:

```
$ sudo apt install paprefs
```

2- Open it:

```
$ paprefs
```

3- Go to the last tab Simultaneous Output and click on the only option there in order to enable the Simultaneous Output.

[image]

4- Restart it:

```
$ pulseaudio -k
```

5- If it fails then you have to restart the daemon

```
$ pulseaudio -D
```

6- Almost finished, go to the system settings and navigate to Sounds options and change the output sounds to the newly added one as below.

[image]

Comment: Which step, or after configured all things? @JBaba

Answer (score 0):

OS : Ubuntu 20.04.
Android studio (snap).

I tried all the methods, none worked for me.

By installing these libs, the sound works now.

sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386

as Gigi mentionned before

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: what's not clear ? your comment is unclear for me