# Audio sound is not playing in Android

Tags: android, audio

I'm learning android app development. Now, when I tried to upload an audio file named "audio.mp3" in res > raw folder in the android studio the audio sound is not playing. and also when running it on an emulator there is no sound. But I found that the file is completely fine. What should I do now?

my code is:

```
package com.example.audiocontroller;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio);
        mediaPlayer.start();



    }
}
```

[here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gR9Ry.png)
[look audio is completely fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfBeO.png)

Comment: have you tried running your app in real device ?

Comment: no  ok I'll try

Comment: thanks a lot, bro.. It's working fine on my real device

Comment: I have added this as an answer Please accept with the right click and upvote it so that others can find it easily.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi the code is perfect the only issue I think is with the emulator you are trying to run. You can check the above app with the real device and you should be able to hear the your `.mp3` file sound as soon as app launches. Other then that you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265202/no-sound-coming-from-android-emulator#:%7E:text=For%20OS%20X%20the%20Android,do%20to%20fix%20my%20issue%3A&text=Click%20on%20%22Sound%20Effects%22,Alert%20volume%20almost%20at%20max.) which describes the problem with the emulator sound.

Comment: yes bro  It's working fine on my real device

Comment: This isn't much of a fix for why the emulator cannot play sounds.