# Android Emulator causing problems to audio to sound on macOS

Tags: audio, android-emulator

I connected my bluetooth headphone to my iMac and started listening to music,
After starting Android emulator the sound quality became horrible.
I am using macOs Mojave 10.14.6 and running Android 11.0 on the emulator.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I had the same issue. This answer fixed it for me! https://stackoverflow.com/a/68392331/1775160

Answer (score 12):

Start the emulator, and then disconnect your headphone, then reconnect it again.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me

Answer (score 3):

For me the sound was muffled as soon as I started up the android emulator.

This solution worked for me:

https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/qsobx4/comment/hkfcxuu/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

> If you don't care about sound on your emulator, you can turn it off:
>
> 1. In the Virtual Device Manager, for the emulator in question, choose "show on disk"
> 2. Look for the file `config.ini` and open it
> 3. Add these 2 lines at the bottom of the file:
>
> hw.audioInput=no
>
> hw.audioOutput=no
>
> - One of those lines is probably already in the list (with a yes), so make sure to remove it

[image]

[image]