# android emulator disable microphone when launching device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

**How do we disable the (virtual) microphone when launching the emulator?**

**Situation**
When launching an Android Studio stock emulator device, the microphone is always enabled and listening.

> **Why would we want this fix**

- **Convenience**, Many users have a microphone headset and when the microphone is enabled, they lose noise canceling and/or stereo. It can be extremely annoying, forcing the user to disconnect the device which swaps the emulator audio + sounds to another microphone/speaker input/output.
- **Security risk**, the microphone is actively listening. Is the data going anywhere? Who knows...this is an unnecessary security risk for any organization, IE a dev is on a (zoom, teams, meetings) call with an open emulator that is using the microphone and listening).

> **Possible Solutions (based on practicality)**

1. flag to disable virtual audio devices (IE the mac's speaker or attached headphones w/ a microphone). I've seen 0 documentation regarding a flag like this.
2. flag to provide to the emulator to disable all audio input (see answer 1). TLDR add the flag `-no-audio`
3. route the android studio emulator (or the mac's microphone audio input) to a virtual device that is not listening. Or have the default OS microphone input set to 0 volume. This can be done via macOSX Automator
4. route the adb emulator to the mac's internal microphone instead of the current microphone to avoid it triggering the headsets microphone settings.

> *The preferred solution*

- Microphone audio-in is disabled when booting the emulator
- Android device audio-out remains and uses the computer's default speakers
- The computer's default microphone is not triggered (at all) to avoid causing a stereo -> mono swap or noise cancellation breakage.

System Information:

- android emulator: 31.2.10.0
- MacOS 12.3.1
- Headsets tested with these issues:

  - Bose NC 700
  - Bose QC series
  - Sony WF-1000XM4
  - Sony WH-1000XM3
  - any headset with a microphone connection macro that does something with the speaker (like talk through) or with the input audio like stereo -> mono.

Answer (score 27):

You can try the approach from here:

[When I start Android Emulator, the audio on my Mac desktop stops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67000474/when-i-start-android-emulator-the-audio-on-my-mac-desktop-stops)
It just works well.

Set the values below into the config.ini from your emulator. It will never bother you again.

```
hw.audioInput=no
hw.audioOutput=no
```

Comment: This is better than using command line option `-no-audio`, since it allows one to only disable input (microphone) or output and to launch the AVDs from Android Studio as usual.

Comment: FYI when relaunching after editing setting via android studio gui, you have to reapply these config settings from your ide sometimes. Solution is to make that config.ini file read-only and then android studio cannot mutate it.

Answer (score 5):

Partial solution based on the emulator's optional arguments which **disables all audio in/out** from the launched emulator.

Running `emulator -help-all` the commands `-no-audio` and `-noaudio` are available to pass.

These commands are the same and disable ALL audio, so no microphone or audio out from the emulator.

Example command

`emulator -avd <name> -no-audio`

**Pros**: Running the above command, launches the emulator with the **microphone disabled**. Headsets and apps like microsnitch will not detect microphone activity.

**Cons**: Clicking on the UI, or playing audio through the emulator will not play audio through the machine (or headset) speakers.