# android emulator not playing any sound at all (including the built in Text-To-Speech engine sample)

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have been trying to get the emulator to play sounds since the last few days but nothing is working
Please see my other questions [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143032/can-the-android-emulator-play-audio) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125780/using-microphone-in-android-emulator-java-android-beginner)
Worst of all is I cannot even make sure whether using the emulator for any job related to sound (recording or playback) is even possible or not. Some forums hint that it's possible and others hint that it's not, but it's not working at all for my case. If nothing else, I am assuming at least the sound functionality built into the emulator OS itself should work. But I just tried to play the sample provided with the built in TTS engine and it is not giving me any output either.

How do I get any kind of sound to come out through the emulator, and is this even possible at all? **- EDIT - : Solved, please read on to see how**

Do I have to get a real device to carry out sound related experiments? Will the same problems be seen in a real device as well? Incidentally, is programming on a real device going to be slow like in the emulator as well? Or is it fast? Or is it still slow but slightly faster than the emulator? I want to make sure that I can do all the basic stuff before I get a real android device.

----- EDIT -----
I finally got the sound working (the TTS sample at least)
it turns out that having snapshot enabled causes this problem
**[MediaPlayer no longer working on the emulator since r10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259849/mediaplayer-no-longer-working-on-the-emulator-since-r10/)  **
But that brings me to a completely different question:
Why in the world would enabling/disabling snapshot have anything to do with audioplayback ??? And besides, if I don't have snapshot enabled it's going to take foreever to load again the next tie I want to use it, so it is essential that I have the snapshot feature enabled

What is the exact cause for this? And why isn't this documented properly?

--- Update ---
In the virtual device with working sound, I restarted it enabling snapshot, and then restarted it again through the snapshot, and now the sound isn't working again. So it looks like this has got to do with enabling or disabling the snapshot, rather than when the snapshot was taken (thus probably making the issues related to windows updates as explained in the answer to he question that I linked, irrelevant)

Comment: I'm not sure what your audio issue is, but I can say that a real Android device will operate much smoother than the emulator. Honestly if you're programming for Android, you should have an Android device at hand - if only to check touch functionality (the mouse on the emulator is a lot more exact than a large finger pressing on a screen), as well as other hardware tests.

Comment: It is always best to use your code on a real device. Can you try ur code on an other Computer. And what OS are you using?