# Error with mediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound) when not in onCreate

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am working on an app that is basically a music library and for each song, when you press button play, the song starts playing. For the moment, my library has 3 items and I am trying to play "sound.mp3", which is in res/raw, for the 3 of them (for the moment).

My problem is when I try to reference the clip, I have a red underline under "this, R.raw.sound". I saw that in most cases "create" is called in onCreate, but in my case, this class in not an activity so I cannot do that ...

Can you guys help me with that? :)

```
    public class ClipsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClipsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private final List<Clips> clip2 = Arrays.asList(
        new Clips("Clip 1", "Artist 1"),
        new Clips("Clip 2", "Artist 2"),
        new Clips("Clip 3", "Artist 3")
);

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private final TextView title;
    private final TextView author;
    private final ImageView play;

    private Clips currentClip;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    public MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        title = ((TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title));
        author = ((TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.author));
        play = ((ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.play));
    }

    public void display(RandomClips RandomClip) {
        currentRandomClip = RandomClip;
        title.setText(RandomClip.title);
        author.setText(RandomClip.author);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Play clip: " + currentClip.title);
                mediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);

                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    Log.d(TAG, currentRandomClip.title + " has stopped");
                }
                else
                {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    Log.d(TAG, currentRandomClip.title + " is playing");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mediaPlayer.create() requests for a context and the file to play. 
The 'this' you are passing as an argument is not a Context (you are in an anonymous class) and therefore you get an error.
You should pass a context. 
Simply pass your activity's context when instantiating your ClipsAdapter.

So in your activity instantiate your adapter :

```
clipsAdapter = new ClipsAdapter(this);
```

In your ClipsAdapter class, create a constructor with one parameter :

```
public ClipsAdapter(YourActivity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

Finally :

```
mediaPlayer.create(activity, R.raw.sound);
```

Comment: Hi Anto! Thanks for your help, I was able to play my program without errors :) So if I understand well, we're using a constructor to set the current activity as the activity in which the sound clip will play. And this is needed because we need an activity to launch the clip.

Comment: I guess it's working now, even though I think that with an emulator we cannot actually play sound ... Am I right?

Comment: Glad to hear. you should be able to play sound using emulator. Then this is another question. Check if this helps    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259849/mediaplayer-no-longer-working-on-the-emulator-since-r10/8262747#8262747